# write numpy array with its size to binary file

Tags: python, file, numpy, binary, tuples

I need to write a 2D numpy array to a file, including its dimensions so I can read it from a C++ program and create the corresponding array.

I have written some simple code that saves the array and it can be read from C++, but if I try to write the array's size first it always gives me an error.

Here's my simple python code:

```
1 file = open("V.bin","wb")
2 file.write(V.shape)
3 file.write(V)
4 file.close()
```

The second line gives the error, I've also tried:

```
n1, n2 = V.shape
file.write(n1)
file.write(n2)
```

But it doesn't work either.

I'm adding the error it shows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    file.write(V.shape[0])
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not int

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure `file.write()` expects a string or buffer.  `v.shape` is a tuple, and passing it as an argument will raise a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.savetext` if you want to save it as ascii.

Alternatively (since it looks like you're dealing with binary data), if you want to save the raw data stream, you could use `ndarray.tostring` to get a string of bytes that you can dump to the file directly.

The advantage of this approach is that you can create your own file format.  The downside is that you need to create a string in order to actually write it to the file.

---

And since you say that you're getting an error on the second line, it's an error because `f.write` expects a string.  You're trying to pass it a `tuple` or `int`s.  You could use `struct.pack` to solve this problem:

```
f.write(struct.pack('2i',*array.shape))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [numpy.save()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) which saves in binary.

Comment: Here's the .npy spec (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/npy-format.txt), so the data can be interpreted from the C++ code after calling `save()`.

Comment: But I need to read first the number of rows and columns from the C++ program. It doesn't save that info, does it?

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. Anyway, thanks, but I already solved it in another way.