# Is there an alternative to numpy.save(file, arr) that will work with pypy?

Tags: python, file, numpy, save, pypy

I have a main program that runs in pypy that creates three 2D numpy arrays. I want to save these to a file and then open them using python and plot them using matplotlib.pyplot.

Currently pypy does not work with numpy.save, is there an easy alternative method to save a group of numpy arrays to a file whilst using pypy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library pickle works with pypy. He's how I saved/loaded the numpy array

```
import pickle 
import numpy
```

save (using pypy):

```
outfile1 = open(r'C:\pythontmp\numpyArray.pkl', 'w+b')
pickle.dump(numpyArray.tolist(), outfile1)
outfile1.close()
```

Load (using python):

```
infile1 = open(r'C:\pythontmp\numpyArray.pkl', 'r+b')
file1 = pickle.load(infile1)                           # This is a list
infile1.close()

numpyArray = numpy.array(file1)                        # This is a numpy array
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [ndarray.tofile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html)() and [numpy.fromfile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html)().  This loses the ability to move data between machines with different endian-ness, but should be even faster than save().

Example:

```
a = numpy.zeros( (5,5) )
a.tofile('a.dat')
b = numpy.fromfile('a.dat')
```

Comment: `tofile` and `fromfile` are also [not supported](http://buildbot.pypy.org/numpy-status/latest.html) by pypy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using python's [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module. There are some examples in answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291118/write-numpy-array-with-its-size-to-binary-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535687/write-a-raw-binary-file-with-numpy-array-data).

Another option is to use an external library like pyfits, or pytables. But I suspect they may not be available on pypy.